# Webdriver does not start in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, webdriver, debian, xvfb

I have the following setup:

- Debian 7 (Headless with Xvfb)
- Xvfb started via daemon at :0
- Selenium 2.44 (declared in pom.xml)
- Mozilla Firefox 35.0.1 (installed from firefox-mozilla-build)
- Jenkins 1.598

I'm getting this exception when running the test:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.Executable.locateFirefoxBinaryFromSystemProperty(Executable.java:143)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.Executable.<clinit>(Executable.java:43)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.<init>(FirefoxBinary.java:59)

testResult(com.Test)  Time elapsed: 0.049 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.Executable
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.<init>(FirefoxBinary.java:59)
```

I've tried so far;

**Setting system property programatically:**

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "/usr/bin/firefox");
```

**Configuring it directly in the Webdriver:**

```
File pathToBinary = new File("/usr/bin/firefox");
FirefoxBinary ffBinary = new FirefoxBinary(pathToBinary);
FirefoxProfile ffProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(ffBinary,ffProfile);
```

**Passing the parameter via Maven**

```
-Dwebdriver.firefox.bin=/usr/bin/firefox
```

All of above has failed.

- I've setup another Jenkins on my Ubuntu 14.04 and it works fine.
- I've run from my IDE, it works fine.
- I've run from commandline on my PC, it works fine.

Is there any other option I can try? Something I overlooked?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My issue seems to be resolved. I had the jenkins running inside a container manager via ProxMox. The firefox and xvfb were not setup within the container, it was in the base machine instead (silly mistake!). After setting up and arranging some configuration within jenkins and the box itself I was able to startup my jobs from inside jenkins. (Using FF 35.0.1 and WD 2.44.0).